# How to replace brackets and add minus sign to a number using PHP

Tags: php

I have this variable-  `$number` which may contain different types of number format.

Type1: `$number=200,000.00 ;` Type2: `$number=(200,000.00) ;` Type3: `$number=(20.50) ;`

If the number has brackets I want to remove the brackets and add a minus sign on its left side.

Example: If the number is `$number=(200,000.00) ;` I want to convert it to `-200,000.00` or in case of `$number=(20.50) ;` I want to convert it to `-20.50` but for `$number=200,000.00 ;` I want to keep it just the way it is.

I have tried this `preg_replace('/[()^\d-]+/', '', $number);`  but its not working.

Could you please show me how to get this done?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do as follows

```
str_replace(array("(",")"),array("-",""),$number);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do what you want:

```
if (strpos($number, "(") !== false && strpos($number, ")") !== false)
    $number = '-'. trim($number, "()");
```

Example: http://codepad.org/Yhb80H0v

Answer (score 2):

Your `$number` has to be a string to let PHP "know" about the parentheses. Use this code:

```
$number = "(1,000.2)";
$number = preg_replace('/\(([0-9,.]+)\)/', '-\1', $number);
print $number;
```